# Choose on which database to eval() on MarkLogic Node Client API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I am using the MarkLogic Node Client API, and would like to [DatabaseClient.eval](https://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/DatabaseClient.html#eval)() some code on every database on the cluster.  But as far as I can tell (and unlike [xdmp.eval](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.eval)() or [/v1/eval](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/eval)) it is not possible to set the content database against which to eval the code.

Did I miss anything?

Extra points for setting the modules database :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the database as part of constructing the client.

https://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/marklogic.html#.createDatabaseClient

In all cases, since you are using the `xdmp.eval()` endpoint, you already have some sharp tools available for the switching of any context (user, database, modules-database) by use of `xdmp.invokeFunction()` inside of your eval.

Comment: Hi @david-ennis-17llamas! Yes, I was afraid that's the response I would get :-) As I have one query to eval on several databases, I hoped I didn't have to instantiate a new client every time. And as I have a repository of queries, I would prefer to leave that responsibility to the part of the code that actually executes it.  If there is no built-in way to achieve this, then I think I will go with passing the query as a string param, and use `xdmp.eval()` on it...

Comment: Technically, you could probably implement your own context switching of content and modules database with declarative XML rewriter. Use one client and do runtime context switching on the request handler. I could see this being possible if you could find a way to set an extra request header or query Param on the requests and monitor for those in a rewriter match rule.  I've done things like that to make ML work as multi-tenant with different modules root and different content dB in the past, but I do not know the Node.js client library and where I would inject the Param on that end

Comment: The use of eval has a side effect of always needing to be compiled including any included modules. Monitor the request log for slow compile times and avoid a try/catch in an eval. Experience has seen it add a strange amount of overhead.  Using eval with same functions over and over can achieve performance gains if you  create an xdmp:function and save it in a server or session field.  The statically compiled version can be re used.